How to create a screener in Pinescript using custom line
I have a pinescript which draw lines based on some custom logic. Code used to draw lines is
if(custom logic)  line.new(bar_index - 1, low, bar_index, low, extend=extend.right, color = color.black, width = 2).
I want write a screener which should notify if 3 continuous candle closes above the line.  eg: if line drawn at 100, if 3 continuous candle closes above 100 then the screener should work. Is it possible in pinescript?
